# What does public://sys/ mean

Tags: php, apache, drupal

I'm trying to find documentation - this is in a Drupal install script, and it's denoting a file path. I'm imagining it's a setting in PHP or Apache to determine a particular directory?

What does `public://sys/` mean?

Comment: `public://` is a stream wrapper...by default in D7 that path points to DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/default/files

Answer (score 2):

public:// refers to the public directory for Drupal. This defaults to /sites/default/files.

public://sys would be referring to the directory sys under public://